# How to group messages in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

How to group messages by people in Facebook?
For example I want to see all messages that I've sent and that I've received from some person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [new Facebook Messaging](http://www.facebook.com/about/messages) to accomplish this.

I think ( cannot remember ) you can search by name within the old messaging system.